# Derivatives for a piecewise defined function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f$ is a function on real line and $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2& x<0\\ 2x+x^2&x\ge 0\end{cases}$. Could any one tell me which of the following is/are true?

1.$f'(0)$ doesn't exist

2.$f'(x)$ exist other than at $0$

3.$f''(x)=2$

4.$f''(0)$ does not exist

I have myself checked that $1$ is true as $\lim x\uparrow 0 f'(x)=0\neq \lim x\downarrow f'(x)=2$ I mean to say lefthand derivative is $0$ but right hand derivative is $2$, but I am not getting how to find $f''$ please help

Comment: relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319957/differentiating-piecewise-functions

Comment: $f''(x)=2$ if $x \neq 0$, so what would you guess the value to be when $x=2$? Can you show $f''(2)$ exists?

Comment: ooooopssssssssss sorryyyy $f'(x)=2x+2,x\ge 0$, $f''(x)=2,x\ge 0$ so $f''(2)=2$

Comment: @miosaki - I messed up. I wanted to have you guess the value of $f''(0)$. Can you show that $f''(0)$ exists? I think I have it right now.

Comment: yes $f''(0)=2$ ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

At each side of $\,x=0\,$ the function is polynomial and thus infinitely differentiable, which already answers (2) and almost-almost (*really* almost!) (3).

Now, just as $\,f'(x_0)\,$ cannot exist if $\,f\,$ isn't defined at $\,x_0\,$ , we get that (4) is true after we take a peek at what we did in (1) ...